# Nested Firebase Queries

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to perform a firebase query within another firebase query like a nested for loop but the outer query runs completely before the inner query begins. how do i achieve this? I am an android and firebase beginner

**Outer Query**

```
 private void retrieveMarkerDetails(final String key) {
    databaseReference = mDatabase.getReference();

    databaseReference.child("Parking Lots").child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            parking_lot_details = dataSnapshot.getValue(Parking_Lot_Details.class);



            Marker marker;

            if (markers.size() != 0) {
                marker = markers.get(key);
                String title = parking_lot_details.getLotName();




                //Calculate Remaining space
                spaceAvailable();
```

Log.i("remaining space avai", String.valueOf(parking_lot_details.getAvailableSpace()));

```
                String snippet = "Available space " + parking_lot_details.getAvailableSpace();

                Log.i("remaining space", String.valueOf(parking_lot_details.getCapacity()));

                // String snippet = "Available space " + parking_lot_details.getCapacity();
                marker.setTitle(title);
                marker.setSnippet("\t" + snippet);
                Log.i("key : ", key);
```

**Inner Query**
This is the inner query that is supposed to run.

```
private void spaceAvailable() {

    spaceAvailable = new int[1];


    //Strip email of dots and use it to access requests, since the requests use the emails
    //of lot owners as keys
    String lot_email= parking_lot_details.getEmail().replace(".","");

    Log.i("lot_email",lot_email);



    databaseReference.child("Requests").child(lot_email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                long requestsMade = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();


                Log.i("Requests ", dataSnapshot.toString());
                Log.i("RequestsMade", Long.toString(requestsMade));
                spaceAvailable[0] = (int) (Integer.parseInt(parking_lot_details.getCapacity()) - requestsMade);

                parking_lot_details.setAvailableSpace(String.valueOf(spaceAvailable[0]));

                Log.i("Space Available ", String.valueOf(spaceAvailable[0]));
                Log.i("Space Available in met ", parking_lot_details.getAvailableSpace());


            }else{

                //if the email does not appear under requests then we assume that no requests have
                //been made and the available space is equal to the lots capacity
                parking_lot_details.setAvailableSpace(parking_lot_details.getCapacity());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
```

**Database**

[image]

**LOG**

[image]

[after trying suggested fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHXCk.png)

Comment: So you say that the first query runs first and the second runs second?

Comment: Yes , the first one runs completely, before the second one , so I end up getting null values

Comment: At which line are you getting null values? Please add the entire error, to see things more clearly.

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: This line of code, works correctly? `Log.i("lot_email",lot_email);` return the user email?

Comment: Yes it does @AlexMamo...Then from that point, the inner query is supposed to start but it doesn't...The Outer query goes to the next item

Comment: I understand now. I can solve your problem if you provide me the content under those childrens under `.child(lot_email)`. The code is not working not because of the nested loops. The loops a re correct. It's not working becase your code is not correct. Please edit your question by adding what I have asked you.

Comment: It is already there, under Requests in the Database image...i just want to get the number of children under each lot_email

Comment: Please see my answer. Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make it work, please change the second query like this:

```
databaseReference.child("Requests").child(lot_email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            long requestsMade = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            Log.d("TAG", dataSnapshot.getKey() + " / No. of childrens: " + requestsMade);

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                long childRequestsMade = ds.getChildrenCount();
                String lot_email = ds.child("lot_email").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", lot_email);
            }
        }else{

            //if the email does not appear under requests then we assume that no requests have
            //been made and the available space is equal to the lots capacity
            parking_lot_details.setAvailableSpace(parking_lot_details.getCapacity());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

To display the values inside those childrens, you need to use a for loop and use `getChildren()` method. In this example it will print only `lot_email`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want to **getChildrenCount()** not getChildren()

Comment: You still can get it. Please see my updated aswer. I have added for both `dataSnapshot` objects. Does it work?

Comment: What is getting `null`? At which line are getting `null`?

Comment: All emails get logged , meaning the code runs the outer query until it exhausts all the nodes before running the inner query runs after the outer has finished

Comment: Change also `addValueEventListener` with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. Should work now. Right?

Comment: Same result,please i have updated the log image after applying your fix [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHXCk.png)

Comment: Why do say that you are getting `null`? You are getting exact what you want. It prints all the email addresses and displays the number of childrens. Is not this what you want?

Comment: No I want to print the email then use that email to fetch the number of children, then print the next email and the number of children and So on in that order

Comment: So, first is not `null`. Just solved the main problem for triggering the inner query. Now, give me a concrete example, by editing your question. What exact do you want to be printed. The example must contain exact data from your database.

Comment: Yeah, not null, sorry, had to comment out some logs. I want to print **ag@gmailcom** in the outer query then immediately get 3 when I call the **getChildrenCount()** in the inner query, then the outer query gets **despite@gmailcom** then immediately get 8 when I call the **getChildrenCount()** in the inner query and So on

Comment: Please see my updated answer. You'll get the email address + the number of childrens. Right?

Comment: thank you very much, it's not exactly what I wanted but I can definitely go on from here. It works!